# NFS not mounting since upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: mount, fstab, nfs

I have several external mounts that are mounted using NFS.

These were working perfectly when I had Ubuntu 14.04, however, I have just updated to 16.04.1 and now they are not mounting.

They are not mounting on startup as specified in /etc/fstab nor am I able to mount them manually.

The fstab reads:

```
10.125.225.120:/var/storage /external-storage/server1 nfs user 0 0
```

All the other mounts are in the fstab following the same model.

When I run `dmseg` I get the following error message for NFS:

```
NFS: nfs4_discover_server_trunking unhandled error -512. Exiting with error EIO
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same problem in 16.04 and recently "fixed" it (with a workaround to disable a kernel module).

If you manually mount the filesystem, then check `/etc/mtab`, you'll probably see a bunch of junk added to the options, e.g. mine became:

```
rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=172.24.25.xx,local_lock=none,addr=172.24.23.xx
```

The key insight is the `sec=sys` bit, that means NFS isn't using any of the GSSAPI/Kerberos authentication stuff. (From context in mailing list issues, I've gleaned the the "-512" error is a generic error for when the "AUTH_GSS upcall" fails.)

You'd expect passing `sec=sys` yourself in `/etc/fstab` would fix this, but it didn't work for me. Nor did explicitly putting `NEED_GSSD=no` in `/etc/default/nfs-common`.

What did work, following [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=168317) was just blacklisting the `rpcsec_gss_krb5` module via modprobe.d:

```
echo 'blacklist rpcsec_gss_krb5' > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rpcsec-gss-krb5.conf
reboot
```

The other caveat is that this is probably a bug, and should just work. There is, for example, [this recent Redhat bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1428941) for "nfs4_discover_server_trunking unhandled error -512" which has been marked as a duplicate of a non-public bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you're desperate, you could look at the changelogs for the NFS packages, all the way back to `nfs-utils (0.1.3-1)` (current version is `1:1.2.8-9ubuntu12 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial`), read the files from the top down to the NFS versions you're running on 12.04:

```
+w3@aardvark:~(0)$ dpkg -l nfs\*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                        Version    Architecture        Description
+++-==========================-===========-=========-==========================
un  nfs-common                 <none>      <none>    (no description available)
un  nfs-kernel-server          <none>      <none>    (no description available)
+w3@aardvark:~(0)$ apt-get changelog nfs-common
Get:1 http://changelogs.ubuntu.com nfs-utils 1:1.2.8-9ubuntu12 Changelog [131 kB]
Fetched 131 kB in 1s (113 kB/s)
       <...snip...>
+w3@aardvark:~(0)$ apt-get changelog nfs-kernel-server
Get:1 http://changelogs.ubuntu.com nfs-utils 1:1.2.8-9ubuntu12 Changelog [131 kB]
Fetched 131 kB in 1s (118 kB/s)
       <...snip...>
```

Comment: Probably not so useful, because the root cause of most NFS regressions I've seen has been in the linux-image package not nfs-utils.